# Dynamic render url image from api

Tags: vue.js

I am completely new on vuejs so I am doing something wrong but I can not see it

I have a method to get the url of the image

```
getImage(url) {
      url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
      this.$http.get(`${url}api`).then((response) => {
        return response;
      }).catch( error => { console.log(error); });
    }
```

And then I am trying to show it on the template like:

```
<img :src="getImageForInstance(service)" class="pull-left">
```

but nothing is happening, and I can not see any image.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Trouble shooting tips: Try setting a breakpoint on the `return response;` line in the browser's dev tools to make sure that the response contains an image url. Then key that url into the browser directly just to make sure that it does in fact return the image you think it does.

Comment: Please provide code for getImageForInstance() and the service.